# Installing linux mint on pc with hybrid drive, ssd is read only (no dual boot)

Tags: linux-mint, readonly, ssd-hdd-hybrid

I'm attempting to install linux mint on my pc with a hybrid drive system (SSD and disk); not dual boot.

I'm booting linux mint from a usb and install is erroring on grub install, but says the installation is successful. Additionally, the pc won't boot into linux. I believe this is partially due to the SSD disk (used for startup).

I've formatted the hard disk, but the SSD is read only and I've attempted `sudo chown` to the mounted SSD partition, but am getting:
`chown: changing ownership of '/media/mint/Windows': Read-only file system`

I've also attempted various things in gparted and gnome disk management.

I have no access to windows, as the boot manager was corrupt and I've deleted the files on the primary disk.

How can I reformat/remove the partitions from the SSD and change it to read/write?

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, that's a bit of an odd issue.

In order to format the drive / edit partitions, you'll *need* to have those partitions unmounted first - otherwise it won't work. You also need to be running your partition editor with `sudo` privileges (or as root) otherwise that will also prevent it from working.

Does the drive have a physical read-only switch you may have flipped? Other than that... the fact your SSD is coming up as read-only (and corrupted the Windows boot manager) strongly suggests (to me anyway) the possibility you may just have a dead drive on your hands. I've seen that failure mode a couple times across a couple different SSDs - they do die sometimes, sadly. It's possible low-level drive commands might be able to stop it acting as a read-only drive for a bit (they often do that once they've reached their wear limits, but sometimes the manufacturer will allow you to bypass the restriction) - although unfortunately I can't remember for the life of me what those commands actually *are*, and in any case you wouldn't want to run your OS off a drive in that state since data corruption would likely become a major issue very quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Follow up: I have another drive in the laptop that I'm going to install linux on, my issue is that I want to prevent the SSD (still containing windows EFI, boot, Windows RE, etc.) from interfering with the boot process of linux. And I'll add that with windows corrupted boot manager, I could only get into bios, but none of the other keys worked (such as boot into safe mode, etc.)

Comment: It won't interfere with the boot process if you do a fresh GRUB install to the new disk, and boot directly from the new disk in the BIOS :)